# Coordinates of raster image from .TAB file

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, mapinfo, tab

I have got a raster image (tif) from a mapping site and an associated .TAB file.  I am trying to correctly map it into CAD/3d model - which I know is set up to the correct coordinates.

The .TAB file is as follows:

```
!table
!version 300
!charset WindowsLatin1

Definition Table
  File "Getmapping_Index_Map.tif"
  Type "RASTER"
  (336451.73,971812.515) (0,591) Label "Pt 1",
  (336451.73,974812.515) (0,0) Label "Pt 2",
  (339451.73,974812.515) (591,0) Label "Pt 3",
  (339451.73,971812.515) (591,591) Label "Pt 4"
  CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 79, "m", -2, 49, 0.9996012717, 400000, -100000
  Units "m"
  RasterStyle 4 1
  RasterStyle 7 16777215
```

I assumed that the coordinates of the corners of the image were (336451.73,974812.515) and (339451.73,974812.515) but while that gets it centred on the right point it is not the right scale.  I can't work out what the (0,0)(591,591) coordinates are for.  It seems to be coming out about 3 times the correct size.

(I can't see a similar question, although that may be due to not knowing the correct terminology.  If so my apologies.)

Comment: are you using AutoCAD Map?

Comment: @vinayan - no just plain autocad (and blender to deal with the 3d).  Nothing that can read the tab file, but I'm sure it should be simple to calculate the coordinates manually.

Comment: one quickfire way would be to open the tiff in Quantum GIS..from there you can get the coordinates on screen..

Comment: @vinayan I'll try that.  Although it seems to be a pretty huge download.

Comment: just download FWTools..its only 22 MB in size..

Comment: The second pair of coordinates is relative to the image — useless. Just use the first pair which is the absolute position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) for this task..This is a command line utility..
A good way to install it would be by downloading the FWTools [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/)

In the FWTools Shell,just run the below command..

```
gdalinfo yourtiffname.tiff
```

you will get all corner and center coordinates on screen like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked.  I actually ended up installing the whole Quantum GIS but this was faster and easier.  I don't quite understand how you get from the data in the file to the data this provides, but it works so thats what matters.

Comment: @neil - Now that you have installed Qgis, you won't regret the decistion..it contains GUIs for most of the gdal tools(if you enable the gdal plugin) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that TIFF solution doesn't work for [OS StreetView](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-streetview/index.html) data, as they only have meaningful coordinates in TAB/TFW files.

`CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 79…` means coordinates are OSGB36 (Ordnance Survey Easting/Northing).

OSGB36 coordinates are written either with a two-letter prefix (Grid References) or without. That file uses version without prefix.

The lines with `Label` define where four corners of the image are.

Take first two numbers from a line with `Label`:

```
(336451.73,971812.515) (0,591) Label "Pt 1",
```

and feed them to a [conversion library like this one](http://www.nearby.org.uk/tests/GeoTools2.html):

```
osgb=new GT_OSGB();
osgb.setGridCoordinates(336451.73,971812.515);

//convert to a wgs84 coordinate
wgs84 = osgb.getWGS84();
```